# What killed Broly for good?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

So in The Legendary Super Saiyan 2, Broly dies at the hands of a three-way Kamehameha, he got blasted into the sun, but was this just an unfortunate but cool event and he would have died at the hands of the powerful Kamehameha anyway, or, was it actually the heat of the sun that killed him?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion, the fact that he's blasted and not disintegrated like Cell for example is the proof that the sun burned him to ashes.

Would he have survived if the sun weren't there ? Well you can't be very close to the sun without dying anyway (radiations, burning~~) so the distance he made to reach the sun should have been enough to disintegrate him if the Kamehameha was enough to kill him. Conclusion: it was powerful but only enough to restrict his movements and push him into the sun.